# how to access value form completionHandler and pass it to another view IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, handler

I'm trying to return String from this method i have two class

first one is for UI and it have two input text user and pass and also i have submit  button , another one only doing the following  method .

I'm trying to return  string from the other class to this class and show the string in alert .

```
#import "LoginPage.h"

@implementation LoginPage

-(NSString *)responsData:(NSString *)loginUrl input1:(NSString *)username input2:(NSString *)password
{

    NSString *urlAsString = loginUrl;
    NSString*test;


    inUsername = username;
    inPassword = password;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:30.0f];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    // Setting Username and password
    NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sended=yes&username=%@&password=%@",username,password];

    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [NSURLConnection
     sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
     queue:queue
     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                         NSData *data,
                         NSError *error)
     {
         if ([data length] >0 && error == nil){ NSString *html =
             [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            // NSLog(@"%@", html);
             self.lastValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",html];
         }
         else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil){
             //NSLog(@"Nothing was downloaded.");
              self.lastValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"No thing was downloaded"];
         }
         else if (error != nil){
           //  NSLog(@"Error happened = %@", error);
              self.lastValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error];
         } }];


    NSLog(@"%@",self.lastValue);
    return  self.lastValue;
}

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



@end
```

i want to use this function in another view ( already i include the header of this file ) but i can't , can any one solve this >

another view

```
- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender {
     LoginPage * login = [[LoginPage alloc]init];
   NSString * dataRe;
    dataRe =  [login responsData:@"http://fahads-macbook-pro.local/ios/post.php" input1:@"admin" input2:@"1234"];
    NSLog(@"%@",login.lastValue);
    if (dataRe != nil) {
        UIAlertView * alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]
        initWithTitle:@"Hello Fahad"
          message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dataRe] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay ! " otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }


}
```

Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the function on the other view, it send an **asynch request** to the web.
So when you do:

```
return self.lastValue;
```

`lastValue` **is still empty** or with the previous value because the `competionHandler` need still to be called. **Code of the completionHandler, is just a peace of code passed to the function, that will be called at right moment**. So the function arrive to the end where is your `return`.

When instead the **completion handler block** is called (because the request has produced a response), you assign the value:

```
self.lastValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",html];
```

Now `lastValue` is right.

So your **function shouldn't return an** `NSString`, but **should return** `void`. 
To pass the string to the other controller, **you should use the** `delegation pattern`.

This is a very quickly example

**SecondViewController.h**

```
@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)lastValueDidUpdate:(NSString *)lastValue;

@end

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<SecondViewControllerDelegate>delegate;

@end
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
@implementation SecondViewController

-(NSString *)responsData:(NSString *)loginUrl input1:(NSString *)username input2:(NSString *)password
{

    NSString *urlAsString = loginUrl;
    NSString*test;


    inUsername = username;
    inPassword = password;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:30.0f];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    // Setting Username and password
    NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sended=yes&username=%@&password=%@",username,password];

    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    __weak typeof (self) weakSelf = self;

    [NSURLConnection
     sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
     queue:queue
     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                         NSData *data,
                         NSError *error)
     {
         if ([data length] >0 && error == nil){ NSString *html =
             [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             // NSLog(@"%@", html);
             weakSelf.lastValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",html];
         }
         else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil){
             //NSLog(@"Nothing was downloaded.");
             weakSelf.lastValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"No thing was downloaded"];
         }
         else if (error != nil){
             //  NSLog(@"Error happened = %@", error);
             weakSelf.lastValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error];
         }

         [weakSelf.delegate lastValueDidUpdate:weakSelf.lastValue];

     }];
}


@end
```

**FirstViewController.h**

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <SecondViewControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) SecondViewController *secondViewController;

@end
```

**FirstViewController.m**

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //your code

    [_secondViewController setDelegate:self];

    //your code
}

//your code

@end
```

**Note that i use a weak reference to self because otherwise you can create retain cycle.**

Comment: thanks for answer do you have any very simple example with pattern ? i search but i couldn't  understand pls

Comment: ok i wrote the code in 1 min but should be good to understand. See the edit bye!

Comment: Thank You you are right . i understand most of things also i read another book about nsurlconnection thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Define a method in your first class i.e. UI class like:

```
- (void)callFromBlock:(NSString*)stringFromResponse
{
    if (stringFromResponse != nil) {
        UIAlertView * alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Hello Fahad"
                              message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",stringFromResponse] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay ! " otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }


}
```

and the submit method should look like:

```
   - (IBAction)submit:(id)sender {
         LoginPage * login = [[LoginPage alloc]init];
       NSString * dataRe;
        dataRe =  [login responsData:@"http://fahads-macbook-pro.local/ios/post.php" input1:@"admin" input2:@"1234"];

}
```

Now instead of return statement in the block, call the **callFromBlock** method from the block when you get the response and pass the string to this method you were trying to return.

Hope it helps.